# How to show ellipsis through css in this html markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very small issue for someone whose have command over css. I have the following markup:

```
<li>
 <div>
  <span>Some text</span>
  <span>Some large amount of text</span>
 </div>
<li>
```

And the css is :

```
li
{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Now i want to show **ellipsis** inside second span which contains large amount of text. How can i do this ?

Can anybody please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you showed us how you styled the `li`s but…

```
<style>
li > span:nth-child(2):before {
    content: '\2026\0020';
}
</style>
<li>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <span>Some large amount of text</span>
</li>
```

In Unicode, U+2026 is the horizontal ellipsis and U+0020 is the space.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5xWhx/

Comment: I misunderstood the asker. Please disregard this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your structure is always like you've marked up (if not, you can use classes - probably a better approach anyway), you can use the `nth-child` selector and `:after` (or `::after`) pseudo-elements, you can do it like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
 <div>
  <span>Some text</span>
  <span>Some large amount of text</span>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* Hide the text in the second span */
li span:nth-child(2){
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

/* Create a pseudo-element after the first span with an ellipsis (UTF-8) as its content */
li span:nth-child(1):after{
    content:" \2026";
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/ewZpz/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this if you have only one liner span. No pseudo elements required

```
li span:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

According to caniuse.com all browser support this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin -

[**http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/**](http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/)

```
$('#target').ellipsis({
    row: 2,
    char: '**'
});
```

You can also try this way (*not fully supported*)

```
span{
    /* essential */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* for good looks */
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response but is there any pure css approach to do this ?

Comment: Make sure you also apply `display:block` to `span`.

Comment: CSS `text-overflow` **is** fully supported in all browsers. The only exception is if there are still people using Firefox 6 or earlier, which is virtually nobody. There's not need to bother with the jquery option for a basic ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if from your example wether you need a dynamic solution of not. So a few questions for you

- Do you know for sure that there will always be more text than the
  container can show?
- Is this text in second span shown only on one line or multiple lines?

I ask this because the `text-overflow:ellipsis;` only works on single line and then only in combination with `white-space:nowrap;`